# В Visual Studio 2015, на Qt 5, как включить отображение информации об объектах Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-studio, qstring

Есть **Windows 10 LTSB 2016**. На ней **Visual Studio 2015**, в нём **Qt5**. Не работает расшифровка всех типов **Qt** в отладчике. Вместо всего отображается один список, в котором в глубине **QArrayData**. Строки не видны. Ставил **Qt VS Addin** и **Qt Tools**. Использовал **natvis** файлы из Интернета(все, какие нашёл). Настраивал VisualStudio: ставил тип отладчика **mixed**, ставил **debug database type** в **debug database for edit and continue**. Ставил **Enable Native Compatibility** и **Enable Managed Compatibility**. Итог - не работает. Список появляется при выключенном **VisualAssist** и выключенном **Intellisence.**, если что-то включить - разницы никакой. Один раз строка в отладчике появилась, и пропала. Как эту ситуацию исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Есть ответ. Нужно снять галочку: **Tools->Options->Debugger->General->Show Raw Structure Of Objects in variables windows**. После этого немного потыкал в настройки, и типы в отладчике появились. **Natvis** не работает со всем, что основано на **Edit&Continue.**